# JPanel data getting changed on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am using three `JButton`s in my swing application. When I click on each button, the corresponding data (formatted in `JTable` with `JScrollPane`) will display on `JPanel`.

Problem: when I resize the `JFrame`, the `JPanel` is replacing with  default button (the button which i was clicked first) information instead of current `JButton` information.

My sample code:

```
      jbutton1.addActionListener(this);
      jbutton2.addActionListener(this); 

    public void actioPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getActionCommand.equals("button1"))
    JPanel.add(table1);
     }
    if(e.getActionCommand.equals("button2"))
     JPanel.add(table1);
      }.......
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more code. Please provide enough so we can reproduce a working example of the problem.

Comment: code posted here talking nothing about descibed issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the `JPanel` will not suddenly replace components or add other components to the panel.

My best guess (and it is a guess due to the limited information in the question) is that none of your buttons actually work and just show the wrong information.

The code you posted only contains an `add` without any revalidation of the layout. Consult the javadoc of the `Container#add` method. When you resize, the layout gets revalidated and you see what is actually contained in the `JPanel`.

Possible solutions:

- Call `invalidate` and `repaint` on your panel as well in your `ActionListener`
- Use a `CardLayout` to switch between the different components

I personally prefer the `CardLayout` option, but it might depend a bit on the situation.

Note that in the code you posted, you add `table1` for both buttons. Might be a copy-paste problem, or a problem with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable express problem clearly.Sorry for your inconvenience.

**JPanel.removeAll()** method has fixed my problem.

I added this method before adding any new component to JPanel. That fixes JPanel unexpected behavior.